# Boolean simplification question - $\neg A\neg B + \neg A\neg C + \neg A\neg BC$

Tags: boolean-algebra

My question is how do I reduce the Boolean simplification question - $\neg A\neg B + \neg A\neg C + \neg A\neg BC$ to get $\neg A+BC$. I'm so lost just been trying to get it for awhile only using the 10 boolean simplification rules.

Comment: The expression reduces to $\neg A(\neg B + \neg C)$.

Comment: If A, B and C are all true then the left side is false (all terms in the sum are conjunctions involving a false statement) but the right side is true (contains a conjunction of true statements).  Something seems typed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

as @an4s has commented,

¬A¬B+¬A¬C+¬A¬BC = ¬A(¬B+¬C)

The equation cannot reduce to  ¬A+BC.

Please check.